# How many ways of creating a PIN code with length of 6 are there?

Tags: combinatorics

How can i calculate the number of possible PIN codes that use only numbers 0-9 and have length are there? No rules,all numbers can be same or different

Comment: What have have you tried so far?

Comment: Hint: how many digits are there, and how do we count the ways a task can be done?

Comment: Any thoughts?  Could you do it if it was length $1$?  Length $2$?

Comment: @SeanRoberson by factorial!?

Comment: @lulu 1 is 10 and 2 is 725760?

Comment: @Murad Not here. Hint: for a (very, very bad) two-digit PIN, how many possibly codes are there? Extend this to three digits, four, then up to six.

Comment: Both of those are wrong. I have no idea where either of your answers came from.

Comment: @lulu i multiplied 2 by 9!,i have no degree in math that's why i came here

Comment: You don't need a degree in math for this.  for length one you can simply list all of them.

Comment: @lulu it's hard when length is 2

Comment: No, it isn't.  first do it for length one though.

Comment: give an example of a PIN code of length one

Comment: I see you changed your answer for length one, $10$ is correct.  Now write out a few for length two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is the multiplication principle: If a task can be done in $m$ ways and another in $n$ ways, the number of ways we can do both is $mn$.

The idea is that you're choosing a digit from $0$ to $9$ and constructing a six digit PIN. We can start with the case of one digit, then two, then I'll leave it to you to extend to six.

There are only ten one-digit PINs: $0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9$. Ten digits.

What about two? We could list them out, but let's be smart: this is the same as the concatenation of two one-digit PINs. We have ten choices for the first digit and ten for the second. How many total two-digit PINs are there? By the multiplication prinicple, this is $10 \cdot 10 = 100$. There are a hundred possible 2-digit PINs.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: 10 to the power of 6?

Comment: Well done. That's exactly it.

Comment: wow i'm a genius

Comment: @Murad you are the most brilliant person I have ever met.

Comment: @yanko My math teacher tells me the same thing

Answer (score 6):

Here is another way to see this

every Pin code of lenth 6 defines a number from 0 to 999,999, that is in total one million numbers.